# Find $u$ such that $u(x, y) + (8xy + 4y)j$ is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem**

Let $v(x,y) = 8xy + 4y$. Find a function $u(x,y)$ such that $f(z) = u(x, y) + jv(x, y)$ is an analytic function of $z = x + jy$ satisfying $f(0) = 0$. Then write $f(z)$ as a function of $z$.

---

**My Work**

$\dfrac{-\partial{v}}{\partial{x}} = \dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}} = -8y$

$\dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} = \dfrac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}} = 8x + 4$

We want to find $u(x, y)$.

$u(x, y) = \int 8x + 4 dx = 4x^2 + 4x + Q(y)$

$\dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}} = \dfrac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{y}}$

$\dfrac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}} = -8y$

$\therefore \dfrac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{y}} = -8y$

$\int \dfrac{\partial{Q}}{\partial{y}} dy = \int -8y dy$

$\implies Q(y) = -4y^2 + C$

$\therefore u(x, y) = 4x^2 + 4x - 4y^2 + C$

Let $C = 0$: $u(x, y) = 4x^2 + 4x - 4y^2$

$f(x + iy) = 4x^2 + 4x - 4y^2 + i(8xy + 4y) = f(z)$

---

I'm unsure if my solution so far is correct, and I'm also unsure of how to write $f(z)$ as a function of $z$. I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to review my solution for correctness and show how to finish it.

Comment: Do you know the Cauchy-Riemann equations?

Comment: @GregMartin Ok, I've edited my post with my work so far. I'm unsure if it's correct, and I'm also unsure of how to write $f(z)$ as a function of $z$.

Comment: Write $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$ and $\bar{z}$ and turn the algebraic crank. What you've done seems correct to me.

Comment: @Nick Thanks for the review. I'm not sure how to write $x$ and $y$ in terms of $z$ in this situation. Any chance of help with this?

Comment: Thanks for the additional information! (That is good stuff to include in the original post, so that people can start providing effective help right away.) Well, there seem to be some quadratic bits floating around. Can you write $f(z)=z^2$ in terms of its real and imaginary parts and see if that inspires you?

Comment: @GregMartin Thanks for the response. I got $z^2 = x^2 - y^2 + 2ixy$. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any obvious way to manipulate it so that it resembles $f(x + iy)$? For instance, there are extra terms in $f(x + iy)$.

Comment: Even if we try $4z^2 = 4x^2 - 4y^2 + 8ixy$, I still don't see how it's possible. Am I misunderstanding something? Anyone?

Comment: Hint: $$f(x+iy)+1=(2x+1)^2-(2y)^2+2i(2x+1)(2y)$$ $$(a+ib)^2=a^2-b^2+2iab$$

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your only problem now is do not know how to convert from $x,y$ to a function of $z$. In which case let me remind you that the properties of a complex number $z = x+iy$ is that the real part of $z$ is $$x=\text{Re}z = \frac{z+\overline{z}}{2}$$

and the imaginary part of $z$ is $$y=\text{Im}z = \frac{z-\overline{z}}{2i}$$

And by using the hint given above by did, you merely write out all the $x$ and $y$ in terms of the property given above.

$$f(z) +1 = (2x+1)^{2}-(2y)^{2} + 2(2x+1)(2y)i$$

By subbing the properties in we thus have $$f(z) + 1 = (z+\overline{z}+1)^{2}-\left(\dfrac{z-\overline{z}}{i}\right)^{2}+2(z+\overline{z}+1)\left(\dfrac{z-\overline{z}}{i}\right)i$$

Would you be able to simplify it now as that is just elementary computations.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you please post a full working of it? I want to see what I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Beautiful. This is exactly the right suggestion if one doesn't see the answer after a bit of hoping for inspiration.

Comment: @ThePointer i have wrote the necessary steps by using Did's hint above.